# Swift 3: UIButton re-enables after midnight

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a button which disables after it is pressed. I need To work out how to get the button re-enable after midnight, or the next day.

So I think I need the button to set the date in a variable after it is pressed. Then an if statement which enables the button if the variable does not match today's date.

Would that be the best way to handle it? Can anyone offer any rough code advice, or possibly advice of an easier way to handle enabling a button after midnight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woow finally some nice question... it's definitely possible... you can check this beautiful documentation by apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Basically you have 2 or more solutions, just 2 comes to my mind right now:

1.) Use UserDefaults or CoreData (Userdefaults for one property is more acceptable I guess

2.) Run backgroundTask as mentioned above..

The first one is very basic solution... you get the date when the button was tapped and if the day is equal to the day you entered the screen later, you keep the button disabled, else you unlock the button and store again the date into the user defaults, this seems to me a little piggy if you ask me..

The second one is much more elegant, in a nutshell... You setup button with some actions and the last thing is disabling it. Then, you setup background Task that every next day the button becomes enabled again...

I am pretty sure you will find the codes somewhere else here, maybe you will find the first algorithm more useful for you..

Anyway wish you best luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Then an if statement which enables the button if the variable does not match today's date.

But the question is, an if statement *where*? Your code can only run if something makes it run. If your app is just sitting there, midnight can come and go and your button won't be enabled because the code that looks to see if it's a different day from the day you saved is not running.

The solution: 
Register to be [notified by the system](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1623059-uiapplicationsignificanttimechan) when the day changes.